# wildcard replace with notepad++

Tags: replace, expression, notepad++, wildcard

I am going to fix a txt file which store about 200,000 record
Every record should consist of 8 column delimit by comma.

However, some data is corrupted which lead to an extra comma. I need to get rid of the extra comma which is likely to happen in the 3rd column

5180,1103131373,Good Day,ABC,12,34,75484,7/1/2014 12:00:00 AM,   <---Correct format
5180,1103131373,Good, Day,ABC,12,34,75484,7/1/2014 12:00:00 AM,  <-- Incorrect

i.e. in this example Good Day should be store in one column instead of two.

i can locate them by regular expression `(.*,.*,.*),(.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,.*,)`
but when i try to replace the extra comma using `\1\2`, some records are missing

Any input is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^,\r\n]*` and add a `^` at the pattern start.

Comment: btw, won't it be better to encapsulate content of 3rd column into double quotes instead of removing the comma? `Good, Day` → `"Good, Day"`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew. Solved the problem with the regex : (^[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*),(^[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,)  replaced by \1\2

Comment: Miroxlav your suggestion is excellent, but i dunno how to write the replace  regex for that. i will think about it. Good Day !

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `.*` with `[^,\r\n]*` and add a `^` at the pattern start.

Use

```
^([^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*),([^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r‌​\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,)
```

and replaced by `\1\2`.

The `[^,\r\n]` negated character class matches any character but a `,`, CR and LF symbols. `\1` is  a backreference to the value in Group 1 (`([^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*)`) and `\2` is  a backreference to the value in Group 2 (`([^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,[^,\r‌​\n]*,[^,\r\n]*,)`).